# how to write SQL Correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have two table **ItemsDetails** and **ItemsSquare**

```
**ItemsDetails** table have following column

ItmDtlId P.K

Itmid F.K

AssetId F.k

Qty 

TDate

Approved

**ItemsSquare** table have following column

ItmSqrId P.k

ItmDtlId F.k

ItmSqQty

Date
```

From **ItemsDetails** table i want to show all the records from **ItemDetails** table also records from **ItemsSquare** table which is having 
ItmDtlId same as in **ItemDetails** and then compare Quantity from ItemDetails table and Itemsquare table as Qty > ItmSqQty

basically i want to access columns of **ItemsSquare** table from **ItemDetails** table based o ItmDtId
as there is no relationship of first table with second table

i am using sql Correlated subquery as follow but i am not getting expected result

Here is my sql query

```
SELECT itd.ItmDtlId
     , it.Itmid
     , itd.Qty
     , itd.Approved
     , as.Assetid
     , as.Assetname
     , itd.TDate 
  from ItemsDetails itd
  join Item it 
    on itd.Itmid = it.Itmid
  join Assets as 
    on itd.Assetsid = as.Assetsid
 WHERE itd.Approved = 1 
   and itd.ItmDtlId = (SELECT itd.ItmDtlId FROM ItemsSquare its WHERE itd.ItmDtlId = its.ItmDtlIdand itd.Qty > ItmSqQty)
```

Please suggest me how i can write Sql subquery effectively to get desired result

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: `itd.ItmDtlId=its.ItmDtlIdand itd.Qty > ItmSqQty` I *think* you're missing an `AND` or `OR` there.

Comment: Why you need subquery? you can achieve this by joining.                   `SELECT itd.ItmDtlId,it.Itmid,itd.Qty,itd.Approved, 
as.Assetid,as.Assetname,itd.TDate from ItemsDetails itd
inner join Item it on itd.Itmid= it.Itmid
inner join Assets as on itd.Assetsid= as.Assetsid
INNER JOIN ItemsSquare its ON itd.ItmDtlId=its.ItmDtlIdand
WHERE itd.Approved = 1 AND itd.Qty > ItmSqQty`

Comment: @Larnu actually she's missing a space character in `ItmDtlIdand`

Comment: `as` is surely a keyword !?!

Comment: What is your expected result and what result are you getting?   Without sample data your description of what you're trying to do is too vague and your broken code doesn't give a clue as to your intent.

Comment: Nice spot @TabAlleman. A good reason why I make sure to CAPITALISE my keywords. :)

Comment: @Strawberry it is in SQL Server ([Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). Maybe that's our confirmation that the OP is using MySQL; as the above wouldn't work in SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu It is in MySQL too! `mysql> SELECT 1 as; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error...`

Comment: @HasanMahmood there is no direct relation of ItemsDetails with ItemSquare table then how can i join that i want to fetch data from ItemDetails table not from ItemSquare

Comment: @shreyas35, but if that's the case you are still creating relation when you write  `WHERE itd.Approved = 1 
   and itd.ItmDtlId = (SELECT itd.ItmDtlId FROM ..... `? Other thing is you missed AND/OR in the sub query? Can you provide some sample data as well?

Comment: Then looks like, regardless of RDBMS, the OP has provided us with an invalid query. Along side the fact that `AS` isn't quoted, we also have `its.ItmDtlIdand itd.Qty`, which should be `its.ItmDtlId AND itd.Qty`. if the OP really is using those aliases, without quotes, then perhaps they are using neither MySQL or SQL Server. I have removed both tags for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that possible that you are referencing your subquery wrongly?

Instead of:

```
...
AND itd.ItmDtlId = (
    SELECT itd.ItmDtlId 
    FROM ItemsSquare its
    WHERE itd.ItmDtlId = its.ItmDtlIdand
      AND itd.Qty > its.ItmSqQty
)
```

To:

```
...
AND itd.ItmDtlId = (
    SELECT its.ItmDtlId 
    FROM ItemsSquare its
    WHERE itd.ItmDtlId = its.ItmDtlIdand
      AND itd.Qty > its.ItmSqQty
)
```

Comment: At least fix the syntax error with `its.ItmDtlIdand itd.Qty` :)